# Is there a way to zoom a 2D canvas in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a 2d mobile app, and I would like to zoom in my screen. I have a `Screen Space - Overlay` in my canvas. I tried this but it does not zoom my screen.

I have attached this script to my canvas:

```
  Vector3 touchStart;
    public float zoomOutMin = 1;
    public float zoomOutMax = 8;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            touchStart = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        }
        if (Input.touchCount == 2)
        {
            Touch touchZero = Input.GetTouch(0);
            Touch touchOne = Input.GetTouch(1);

            Vector2 touchZeroPrevPos = touchZero.position - touchZero.deltaPosition;
            Vector2 touchOnePrevPos = touchOne.position - touchOne.deltaPosition;

            float prevMagnitude = (touchZeroPrevPos - touchOnePrevPos).magnitude;
            float currentMagnitude = (touchZero.position - touchOne.position).magnitude;

            float difference = currentMagnitude - prevMagnitude;

            zoom(difference * 0.01f);
        }
        else if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            Vector3 direction = touchStart - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            Camera.main.transform.position += direction;
        }
        zoom(Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel"));
    }

    void zoom(float increment)
    {
        Camera.main.orthographicSize = Mathf.Clamp(Camera.main.orthographicSize - increment, zoomOutMin, zoomOutMax);
    }
```

Comment: The `orthographicSize` just changes the cameras rendering size ... since you most probably have a screenspace overlay canvas the canvas is not affected by that at all since it is rendered always on top depending only on the screen pixel dimensions which are not changing

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing camera orthographic size you can try the other way round and change scale of canvas itself in both axis equally something like

Edit : I am editing the script to explain better. Just attach this script to Parent of the objects you want to zoom in to. You must not attach this on canvas as it will have no effect instead you can create an empty parent and move all of the objects to be zoomed in inside that parent as children and attach this script to parent.

```
public class ZoomTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float zoomOutMin;
    [SerializeField] private float zoomOutMax;

    private void Update()
    {
        float MouseWheelAxis = Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel");
        if (MouseWheelAxis != 0)
        {
            zoom(MouseWheelAxis);
        }
    }

    void zoom(float increment)
    {
        float ClampX = Mathf.Clamp(transform.localScale.x + 
                                   increment, 
        zoomOutMin, zoomOutMax);
        float ClampY = Mathf.Clamp(transform.localScale.y + 
                                   increment, 
        zoomOutMin, zoomOutMax);
        transform.localScale = new 
        Vector2(ClampX ,ClampY);
         
    }
```

}

Comment: there's an error `Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0117 'Canvas' does not contain a definition for 'gameobject' ` can you help me to solve this one, please? thanks

Comment: See my edited answer @Jigen Otsuki